# Angular 2 and Input Range

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Input range and ngForm is always null in IE 11.

We have sample form where we have ngForm and it works fine in chrome but input range control return always null and cannot get values of selected range.

Expected/desired behavior
Should return value for input range for IE 11

Demo plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/owcvOZj99gUMB65TZXMx?p=preview

Angular version:** 2.0.0-beta.17

```
`import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';
http://plnkr.co/edit/owcvOZj99gUMB65TZXMx?p=preview
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
  template: `  
  <div class="ui raised segment">  
    <h2 class="ui header">Demo Form</h2>  
    <form #f="ngForm"  
          (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.value)"  
          class="ui form">

      <div class="field">  
        <label for="input0">Number</label>  
        <input type="text"  
               id="input0"  
               placeholder="Number"  
               ngControl="number0">  
      </div>

      <div class="field">  
        <label for="inputRange0">Range</label>  
        <input type="range"  
               id="inputRange0"  
               placeholder="Range"  
               ngControl="range0">  
      </div>
      <label>{{f.skuRange}}</label>

      <button type="submit" class="ui button">Submit</button>  
    </form>  
  </div>  
  `
})
export class App {
    onSubmit(form: any): void {
      console.log(form);
      console.log('you submitted value:', form);
    }
  }
`
```

Browser: [IE 11 ]

Language: [ TypeScript : Version 1.8.10]